# Adding a line after an import statement

Tags: bash

How do I add a line after the following import statement

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

My code currently doesn't make a change:

```
sed -i "/\import { NgModule } from '@angular\\/core';\[/ {a\\import { TestModule } from '@angular\\/core';
}" ./target/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Comment: Why is there a "`\[`" at the end of the pattern? Also, why is the first "`i`" escaped?

Comment: Since your pattern contains `/`, typical practice is to use a different delimiter for the address.  eg `sed '\|^import { NgModule } ...|...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below,

```
sed  '/import { NgModule } from '@angular\\/core';/ a import { TestModule } from '@angular\\/core';' ./target/src/app/app.module.ts
```

---

I missed single quotes,

```bash
sed  "/import { NgModule } from '@angular\\/core';/ a import { TestModule } from '@angular\\/core';" ./target/src/app/app.module.ts
```

Comment: I missed singie quotes, so I modified.